# What shape must that vase have?

Tags: calculus, geometry, related-rates

I am trying to figure out its proper reasoning. I need its answer. Is this related to differential equations? Suggestions and explanations would be appreciated.

> If we punch a hole in the bottom of a cylinder with water in it, the height of the water will decrease faster at the beginning that towards the end. This is because the pressure on the bottom decreases when the water level decreases. A little more precise:
>
> > The speed at which water flows out of a container is proportional to the height:.
> > $$V'(t) = -kh$$
> > where $V(t)$ is the volume of the water in the vase, $h$ is the height from the hole up to the water level and $k$ is a constant. $V'(t)$ may well be given in liters per second.
>
> Now imagine that you are going to turn a vase that is such that the height decreases with constant speed when you make a small hole in the bottom. What shape must that vase have?

---

Links:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTvzz.jpg

Comment: [Torricelli's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law) says that the flow rate is proportional to the square root of the height of the liquid (pressure is proportional to the square of the velocity of the flow).

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

When the vase has radius $r(h)$ at height $h$ from the bottom then we also have
$$V'(t)=\pi\> r^2(h)\> h'(t)\ .$$

Comment: Sir, can I have precise solution? I don't understand what we have to find basically.

Comment: @WaseemF-NameAliNawaz: Consider what you have and what is given in this answer. The two give a good differential equation.

Comment: I understand what has asked for. But I don't know to start its construction and proper explanation.

Comment: @WaseemF-NameAliNawaz: can you turn "height decreases with constant speed" into an equation involving $h$?

Comment: No, sir. I don't know how to start the answer. If you provide proper solution, then I will try my level to understand it. But for now I don't know. It is typical for me. I understand what question is demanding but I don't know how to answer it in proper way. What we have to find here r, h or v???

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123377/discussion-on-answer-by-christian-blatter-what-shape-must-that-vase-have).